# Is Windows GUI FPS lower than refresh rate?

Tags: windows, display, gui, refresh-rate, fps

I'm just wondering why in a lot of videos on youtube with 60fps Windows interface looks much smoother than my real interface? If I can see smooth interface on video why I can't see it on my actual computer? To demonstrate what I mean if you have 60Hz display please open this example video, set 1080p60 quality and look how smooth mouse cursor and windows moves. And try to move mouse/windows on your PC.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ai8tDQjQ3Yw

Any ways to increase FPS?

Comment: Sorry to say, but that is how I see it on my own computer too. I have a smooth mouse cursor. If you don't then there i ssomething on your computer that is not working correctly. Are your video card drivers installed and up to date? No programs in the background that interfere?

Comment: Playing a video is, in some ways, easier or at least more consistent than actually performing a lot of operations to piece together windows and composite a desktop and then draw a mouse pointer on top. Depending on your graphics card or chip it simply might not be up to the task, particularly if the system is quite old.

Comment: My computer is powerful enough (one of latest 8-core i7 + GTX 2060, 32Gb RAM) and when I connect 120Hz monitor - everything is very smooth. I see difference on all 60Hz monitors everywhere (home, work, friends, computer stores), not just my computer. However same 60Hz displays shows smoothly on recorded 60fps videos.

Comment: With those specs it is probably not a graphics card issue then but could be your eyesight and brain processing that is masking the movement. You move the mouse and expect to see the cursor move, so you move your eyes. Your eye movement results in [saccadic masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccadic_masking) which effectively "hides" the motion. With higher refresh rates or videos (less predictable by you) you might be moving your eyes slightly slower and seeing the motion better and so less masking occurs. It sounds like this is a meatware problem rather than a hardware one.

Comment: One way to test: put an image on the screen where you can focus on a specific point. Move the mouse cursor around/over that point but **do not** follow it with your eyes. Focus only on the point, not the cursor. Does it look "smooth"?

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for! did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, had to buy 144Hz monitor